# Rxjs map only first emition

Tags: rxjs

Is there an operator that can let me map just the first emit ?

something like

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { mapFirst } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const example = source.pipe(mapFirst(val => val + 10));
//output: 11,2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Check the index `map((value, index) => { if (index === 0) ... }`

Comment: @cartant thanks but I knew I could do this, I was hoping for some home baked operator, for the sake of a nicer syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a user-land operator to do it:

```ts
import { OperatorFunction } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

function mapFirst<T, R>(selector: (value: T) => R): OperatorFunction<T, T | R> {
    return map<T, T | R>((value, index) => (index === 0) ? selector(value) : value);
}
```

And you'd use it as you have in your question.

Comment: thanks, but it's a little unfortunate that the result can't be typesafe like `[T, ...R]`

Answer (score -1):

Use `first` operator or `take(1)`

```
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const example = source.pipe(first());
```

Comment: this does not emit after that first value anoymore